# Why is StringTokenizer giving different outputs when used in a while loop and a for loop

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I used `StringTokenizer` to get the tokens of a string. But I get two different outputs when I tried to print all the tokens in that `StringTokenizer`, using a for-loop and a while-loop.

```
String string="She is an attractive girl, isn't she?";
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer=new StringTokenizer(string,",");
```

***when I tried to print all the tokens using a for loop***

```
for (int i=0;i<stringTokenizer.countTokens();i++)
  System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
```

***output***

She is an attractive girl

***when I tried to print all the tokens using a while loop***

```
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements())
  System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
```

***output***

She is an attractive girl

isn't she?

I want to know why the while loop gives the expected two tokens and the for loop doesn't gives the two tokens.

Comment: This blog post can help you: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: oh, I am sure she is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `countTokens()` value is decreasing as you call `nextToken()`. In the first run `countTokens()` is returning `2` for the two entries found. When you call `nextToken()` the first time this number is decreased to `1` since there is only one entry left to read. But this means that the `for` loop will result in

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
```

And the `for` loop variable `i` is already at value `1`. So, since `1<1` is `false` your `for` loop terminates without reading the second entry.

You can save the count of tokens in a variable first and then use it in your `for` loop.

```
int count = stringTokenizer.countTokens();
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
}
```

This way the `countTokens()` method gets called only once (with the correct value) and not after every `nextToken()` call with decreasing remaining token count.